# Creating a new SharePoint column using Graph REST API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I've been working on a function that puts a value in a list column if it exists. However, in the case that it doesn't exist (which I check using `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveID}/list/columns"`), I'd like it to make a list column. How do I create a new column in SharePoint using Microsoft Graph's REST API? I've scoured the documentation but have thus far come up short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [API documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/list?view=graph-rest-beta), there is no such an endpoint to update a list. I believe the related functionality has not been released. You can submit the feedback on [Microsoft Graph Feature Requests](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) or turn to the [old sharepoint rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn600182(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#request-examples-11):

- https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/create-list-column-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP** :

POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/tables/{id|name}/columns](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/%7Bid%7D/workbook/tables/%7Bid%7Cname%7D/columns)

Content-type: application/json

Content-length: 81

{
"id": 99,
"name": "name-value",
"index": 99,
"values": "values-value"
}

**Response : HTTP**

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 81

{
"id": 99,
"name": "name-value",
"index": 99,
"values": "values-value"
}

Response :
If successful, this method returns 201 Created response code and WorkbookTableColumn object in the response body.

For more details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/table-post-columns?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: This looks to me like a 'workbook' table column. I'm hoping to add a column to my list (like the default "Name" or "Modified By" columns). Are these the same thing?